# FirebaseUI - Upgrading Anonymous Users. Merge Conflict

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have been able to set up authentication with firebaseui properly using uiConfig. However, if an anonymous user signs in with an existing user it doesn't call signInFailure. Instead, I get "Uncaught uh {code: "auth/credential-already-in-use"..."

```
uiConfig = {
    signInFlow: "redirect",
    autoUpgradeAnonymousUsers: true,
    signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ],
    signInSuccessUrl: '/home',
    callbacks: {
        signInSuccessWithAuthResult: (authResult) => {
            if(authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser){ //If new user
                const createUser = this.props.createUser(authResult)
                const signIn = this.props.signIn()
                Promise.all([createUser, signIn]).then( () =>{
                    this.props.history.push('/home')
                    return true
                }
                )

            } else{ //If existing user
                return true
            }
        },
        signInFailure: (error) => {
            console.log('got here')
            var cred = error.credential
            return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(cred)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: I was not able to

Comment: In my case, actually that error is being logged by the library and it seems innocuous as things are mostly working fine even with that logged error